# Override BQL used for PXProjection on SOShipmentPlan

Tags: acumatica

I have a need to override the Select statement being used for the `SOShipmentPlan` PXProjection/DAC, namely, removing the

`And <INPlanType.isFixed, Equal<boolFalse>`
condition.

I can override all of the `CreateShipment()` logic and bring in any other necessary routines into an `SOShipmentEntry_Extension` class, to the point where I finally can use my own version of a `SOShipmentPlan` class, but that all seems needlessly complex when all I want to do is override the select for the PXProjection attribute.  Overriding `CreateShipment()` and supporting routines also seems like a quick way to get in trouble come time for upgrades.

So, is there an easy way to override the `PXProjection`'s BQL, or am I stuck overriding all kinds of code?

**UPDATE 1**

Based on a link provided below ([stackoverflow.com/a/41540659/7376238](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41540659/7376238)), I feel like I'm close.  Here's the block of code I end up with:

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
  public class SOShipmentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers

    #endregion

    [Serializable]
    [PXProjection(typeof(Select2<SOOrder,
      InnerJoin<SOOrderType, On<SOOrder.FK.OrderType>,
      InnerJoin<INItemPlan, On<INItemPlan.refNoteID, Equal<SOOrder.noteID>>,
      InnerJoin<INPlanType, On<INItemPlan.FK.PlanType>>>>,
    Where<INItemPlan.hold, Equal<boolFalse>,
      And<INItemPlan.planQty, Greater<decimal0>,
      And<INPlanType.isDemand, Equal<boolTrue>,
      And<INPlanType.isForDate, Equal<boolTrue>,
      And<Where<INItemPlan.fixedSource, IsNull, 
        Or<INItemPlan.fixedSource, NotEqual<INReplenishmentSource.transfer>>>>>>>>>))]
    [PXSubstitute()]
    public partial class SOShipmentPlanCst : SOShipmentPlan
    {
      int x = 0;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  Not sure of where I'm supposed to put the code.  I've tried putting the class definition inside and outside of `public class SOShipmentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>` class (currently inside the extension class as shown).  No luck either way.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS ANSWER DIDN'T WORK**

Fair warning... I have not done this to a PXProjection before, so you'll have to see if this works.  The nature of extensions tends to allow overriding **views** by simply redefining them.  I have not done this myself with a projection, but I suspect it will be similar. Give it a try and see if you get the desired results.  All I can say about testing it is that "it compiled" when I added to my project and removed the INItemPLanType.isFixed condition.

```
public class SOShipmentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
{
    [PXProjection(typeof(Select2<SOOrder,
        InnerJoin<SOOrderType, On<SOOrder.FK.OrderType>,
        InnerJoin<INItemPlan, On<INItemPlan.refNoteID, Equal<SOOrder.noteID>>,
        InnerJoin<INPlanType, On<INItemPlan.FK.PlanType>>>>,
        Where<INItemPlan.hold, Equal<boolFalse>,
        And<INItemPlan.planQty, Greater<decimal0>,
        And<INPlanType.isDemand, Equal<boolTrue>,
        And<INPlanType.isForDate, Equal<boolTrue>,
        And<Where<INItemPlan.fixedSource, IsNull, Or<INItemPlan.fixedSource, NotEqual<INReplenishmentSource.transfer>>>>>>>>>))]
    public partial class SOShipmentPlan : IBqlTable { }
}
```

Comment: It's always a good bet to try copy pasting first to override. If that doesn't work out, there's a more convoluted solution here as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41540659/7376238

Comment: I actually have tried the above code snippet, both inside and outside of ```SOShipmentEntry_Extension``` class, but that didn't work.  The SF you linked to looks promising, but I can't quite figure out how to get it to work.  I'll update my question with the code that results from attempting the SF link you supplied.